# Reading a file and extracting data using a regex in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to echo out the names/paths of the files that are written in `logfile.txt`. For that, I use a regex to match everything before the first ocurrence of `:` and output it. I am reading the `logfile.txt` line by line:

```
<?php

$logfile = fopen("logfile.txt", "r");

if ($logfile) {
    while (($line = fgets($logfile)) !== false) {
        if (preg_match_all("/[^:]*/", $line, $matched)) {
            foreach ($matched as $val) {
                foreach ($val as $read) {
                    echo '<pre>'. $read . '</pre>';
                }
            }
        }
    }

    fclose($logfile);
} else {
    die("Unable to open file.");
}

?>
```

However, I get the entire contents of the file instead. The desired output would be:

```
/home/user/public_html/an-ordinary-shell.php
/home/user/public_html/content/execution-after-redirect.html
/home/user/public_html/paypal-gateway.html
```

Here is the content of `logfile.txt`:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

/home/user/public_html/an-ordinary-shell.php: Php.Trojan.PCT4-1 FOUND
/home/user/public_html/content/execution-after-redirect.html: {LDB}VT-malware33.UNOFFICIAL FOUND
/home/user/public_html/paypal-gateway.html: Html.Exploit.CVE.2015_6073
```

*Extra question: How do I skip reading the first two lines (namely the dashes and emtpy line)?*

Comment: use `preg_match` instead of `preg_match_all`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go:

```
<?php
# load it as a string
$data = @file("logfile.txt");

# data for this specific purpose
$data = <<< DATA
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

/home/user/public_html/an-ordinary-shell.php: Php.Trojan.PCT4-1 FOUND
/home/user/public_html/content/execution-after-redirect.html: {LDB}VT-malware33.UNOFFICIAL FOUND
/home/user/public_html/paypal-gateway.html: Html.Exploit.CVE.2015_6073
DATA;

$regex = '~^(/[^:]+):~m';
# ^ - anchor it to the beginning
# / - a slash
# ([^:]+) capture at least anything NOT a colon
# turn on multiline mode with m

preg_match_all($regex, $data, $files);
print_r($files);
?>
```

---

It even skips both your lines, see [**a demo on ideone.com.**](http://ideone.com/aNRV65)

Comment: I would've favored this answer but it outputs two arrays. The first one includes the `:` and the second starts without a slash before the names of the files.

Comment: Do you need the slashes? Updated the answer, loop over `$files[1]` to have your files. Additionally updated the ideone.com demo.

Comment: Let's say I do. Just because they are present in the file and I might need them for specific cases in the end. But I would also like to have just one array.

Comment: If you can be sure that there is always a colon (`:`)  in every line with a slash at the beginning, you could as well use: `$regex = '~^/[^:]+~m';` (no parentheses anymore) - bear in mind though that it will match much more if there's no colon (anything *not* a colon includes newline characters as well).

Comment: What purpose did the parentheses serve? And I accepted your answer, thank you.

Comment: @McJohnson: They **capture** (aka save it) on top of **matching**.

Answer (score 3):

`preg_match_all` returns all occurrences for the pattern. For the first line, it will return:

`/home/user/public_html/an-ordinary-shell.php`,
an empty string, 
`Php.Trojan.PCT4-1 FOUND`
 and an other empty string

that don't contain `:`.

to obtain a single result, use `preg_match`, but to do that using `explode` should suffice.

To skip lines you don't want, you can for example build a [generator function](http://php.net/manual/en/language.generators.overview.php) that gives only the good lines. You can also use a stream filter.

Comment: Silly me. I forgot the difference between `preg_match_all` and `preg_match`. Did it with `preg_match` and explode. Thank you for your time. I would've accepted your answer as well but I can only accept one.